# AllChars compose key doesn't work in EmacsW32 and mintty

Tags: windows, keyboard, compose-key

I use [AllChars](http://sourceforge.net/projects/allchars/files/) 5.0.181 on a Windows XP machine to have a compose key (set to the <kbd>Menu</kbd> key). It works in most applications (e.g. <kbd>Menu</kbd> <kbd>^</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> produces `â`).

However, there are two applications where this doesn't work:

- In [EmacsW32](http://www.ourcomments.org/Emacs/Emacs.html) 23.1 (reporting as `GNU Emacs 23.1.50.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600) of 2009-11-04 on LENNART-69DE564 (patched)`: when I press <kbd>Menu</kbd> <kbd>^</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd>, I get the message `<packet> is undefined`.
- In mintty 0.8.2 from Cygwin, <kbd>Menu</kbd> <kbd>^</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> has no effect.

<kbd>Menu</kbd> <kbd>Menu</kbd> does what <kbd>Menu</kbd> would do without AllChars in all applications, even EmacsW32 and mintty.

I'm looking for either a way make AllChars work in Emacs and mintty, or another way to get a compose key (*not* dead keys) that works in all applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in mintty is that it doesn't process the VK_PACKET virtual key code, which is what AllChars uses to send composed characters to applications. Fixed on svn trunk, for version 0.9.

I'd guess it's the same issue in emacs.

Comment: Emacs 24 (specifically the 24.0.50.1 checkout from 2010-09-16 distributed as [EmacsW32](http://www.ourcomments.org/Emacs/Emacs.html)) works, and your patch to mintty does work. Thanks again!

Comment: I am using mintty 1.0.1 and AllChars does not work either. There seems to be a regression.

Comment: @Sam Can you enter a mintty issue with details of how it's failing? I've just tried it and it seems fine.

Comment: @ak2: sure, I was about to, but I'm not sure what additional information to provide. Maybe the difference is that I am using RightAlt instead of the default RightCtrl? The issue is at http://code.google.com/p/mintty/issues/detail?id=298.

Comment: @ak2 by the way, since I had too many issues with AllChars I have written my own compose key software for Windows, and it is a lot more robust — if you want to have a look at it, it’s called [WinCompose](https://github.com/SamHocevar/wincompose).